# Compare a button color to another color - android

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to compare a button color , to see if it's red or green, because based on its background color, it's color is going to change onClick. The click part is not a problem, but comparing the colors is.
I know that there are topics about things like this, but none of them answered my question.
To make it easier to understand: 
Example : if( button is green ){
                //do stuff}
Here I's my code:

```
public class changeColor {


public changeColor(View btn){
    ColorDrawable btnColor = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();


    if(btnColor == red  ){
        // do stuff

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getColor()` to get the color in `int`. Then compare it with other colors. For example, for red use below.

```
if((btnColor.getColor()&0xffffff) == 0xff0000){
    // do stuff

}
```

`0xff0000` is hex notation for red color.
To get hex codes for other colors, check a website like [this one](http://www.hexcolortool.com/).